# Android Recyclerview auto horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Google News app (Android) has auto horizontal scrolling that automatically swipe after a short period of time. It also have a time bar below, to show how long before the auto swipe happens. Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
   int value =  0;
   myHandler = new Handler();
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    eventPhotosRC.setLayoutManager(new 
  LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 
  false));

  while(value<list.size()){


 Runnable r = new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run(){
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition((value));
 }
};

Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(r, 1000); 

value+=5; }
```